# User Input in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, fonts, user-input, glut, cin

So I'm creating a simple game (in this case it's a asteroid clone game) and while i press "Start Game" in my Menu section I get to this window:
[image: http://i.imgur.com/BhSRZ50.png]
Now I want to put my nick in that frame but I have no clue how to do it since std::cin doesnt work... I also heard that there is no user input handling in OpenGL... so in such case how to deal with it? So basicaly I want a blinking bar on the left of that frame which indicates where the writting begins (like in MS Word for example) and a user input handling like cin in console application (the blinking bar is not THAT important :P ). Is there a simple way to do it? For the "please enter your nick" I have used glutBitmapCharacter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using GLUT, you can create [callback functions](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node45.html) to handle device/user input.

For this, I would suggest glutKeyboardFunc, glutKeyboardUpFunc, glutSpecialFunc, and glutSpecialUpFunc. The two keyboard functions handle anything that can be represented by an [ascii](http://www.asciitable.com/) character. The two special functions handle things like shift, control, and alt. I think that you will find [this tutorial](http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/keyboard.html) helpful.

Happy Coding!

Comment: So I guess there is no other possibility than using glut? Cuz this will force me to change the entire main code and thats something I want to avoid to be honest... something like getchar() can't come in handy? If there's really nothing else than the glut functions then I will use it but it's better to ask first :P

Comment: You could use SDL: http://www.libsdl.org/ but I assumed glut because that is what you tagged the post as. Other than glut or sdl, you could use operating system specific hooks, but that limits portability. For linux, a combination of kbhit and getch() from conio.h would do it. For Mac OS X and Windows, it gets rather complicated... https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/HID/new_api_10_5/tn2187.html  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg153546%28v=vs.85%29.aspx  I would say that it is easier to just use glut or SDL. :)

Comment: Thanks Ned! I tried to use the SDL library, I wrote a user input class (I read the Lazy Foo tutorial) but somehow it didn't work so I grabbed for the system functions. I used GetKeyState(key) and a while loop. So basically I set the key=33 (33 because when u look at the ASCII table under 33 u will find '!' the first char that interests me) and then a simple if(GetKeyState(key) <0) inside the while(key <127) loop, a string nick+=key and a key++; Thats all :) perhaps not a very optimized way to handle this problem but definitely a EASY! one.